# How to prevent proliferation of development dependencies with project.json floating versions?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, project.json

I have a test utilities project (call it `Utilities.Test`) that specifies a nuget package as development dependency in its `project.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "devdep": {
        "version": "*",
        "type": "build"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {}
  },
  "supports": {},
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  }
}
```

I package `Utilities.Test` as a nuget package and attempt to consume it in a test application (call it `MyProject.Test`), specifying the version as a floating value in the `MyProject.Test` `project.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "utilities.test": {
            "version": "*",
            "type": "build"
        }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  }
}
```

When I do this, I get the following compilation error: `"Unable to resolve devdep (>= x.x.x) for .NETFramework, Version=4.5"`.  I've found two ways to resolve the issue:

- Include `devdep` as a reference (with floating version) in the `MyProject.Test` `project.json` file as well.
- Specify a concrete version number for `Utilities.Test` in the `MyProject.Test` `project.json` file.

Neither of these solutions is acceptable.  I thought the whole point of specifying a package as a development dependency was to prevent it from being captured as an install dependency.  How do I prevent `devdep` from being proliferated as a dependency when using floating versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `<developmentDependency>true</developmentDependency>` to the nuspec file for `Utilities.Test`.  This was already specified in the .nuspec file for `devdep`, so I'm unclear why that would be insufficient to prevent its proliferation.  Also totally unclear now what the purpose of the `"type": "build"` tags in the `project.json` are for - would welcome any insight on these two questions.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.